# Add text to field based on data from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

So I am still learning SQL, and I've been able to complete most of the tasks I have, but even the context of the code for this task eludes me.

So this is a small Oracle SQL DB and the task is: 
`UPDATE` the product's description to include on the following string on those products that have not been ordered yet: "Special promotion: 25% off."

So I need to add the text "Special promotion: 25% off" to the end of the value in `PRODUCT.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION` if `PRODUCT.PRODUCTID` does not appear anywhere in the column `ORDERDETAIL.PRODUCTID`.

Comment: Seems like a homework assignment and simple enough. What have you tried so far?

Comment: It is a homework assignment. Just 1 of 20 questions. I started with a simple UPDATE concept using a WHERE statement to find values (or lack there of) but I can't really even begin to consider how to start the DML. I believe I understand the steps that need to happen, I just can't translate the process to code in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint:

"`PRODUCT.PRODUCTID` does not appear anywhere in the column `ORDERDETAIL.PRODUCTID`"  .. suspiciously sounds like it .. [`NOT EXISTS`](http://www.dbanotes.com/database-development/using-exists-in-oracle-sql-queries/).

> `UPDATE PRODUCT
>  SET    PRODUCTDESCRIPTION = PRODUCTDESCRIPTION || ' Special promotion: 25% off'
>  WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
>     SELECT 1
>     FROM   ORDERDETAIL
>     WHERE  ORDERDETAIL.PRODUCTID = PRODUCT.PRODUCTID
>     );`

It's a silly assignment, though. Nobody in this right mind would update the description like that. One would append the string dynamically in the display instead of writing it into the column.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Yes we're learning about the UPDATE command, and I thought the SET would wipe out the field, which is correct, I just didn't know you could SET the original value + 'text'.

Thanks for getting me out of a tough spot!